# Upgrade to Angular 6- Rxjs 6 breaks HttpPost

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, angular-httpclient, rxjs6

Traditionally httpService.post(url, payload, options) returned an  `Observable<T>` whose could be easily accessed within the subscription. For example in the following example, the post would return an `Observable<string>` which could be easily used as

```
this.httpClientService.post<string>(url, payload, options)
.subscribe(x=> console.log(x));
```

But now, after the upgrade, the return type has changed to `Observable<HttpEvent<string>>` which throws the error

```
'Observable<HttpEvent<{}>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<string>'
```

in my old code.

Can someone help me with how this new `Observable<HttpEvent<T>>` is parsed

Comment: `this.httpClientService.post<Object>(url, payload, options)
.subscribe(x=>{
console.log(x)
})` try changing the code to this format

Answer (score 0):

What's your rxjs version?
With Angular 6 upgrade, I guess rxjs version is also updated, and so does the imports from rxjs.
You can use [rxjs-compat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-compat) for backward compatibility, so that there would be no need for you to change imports and syntax.

Comment: this has to do with the angular httpclient service not rxjs i believe

Comment: You're right! I read your comment below, and as you mentioned that - "http post have 'observe' and 'responsetype' settings", therefore this means that you're listening to Http Event Types like when the request is send or when response is got. You can set Observe to reponse like this { observe: 'response' } or remove observe property anyway, so by default it will return the response and not Http event types

Comment: It defaults to event, I changed it to body

Comment: Found this one [https://alligator.io/angular/httpclient-intro/](https://alligator.io/angular/httpclient-intro/), and it read that - By default the HttpClient returns the body of the response

Answer (score 0):

change post type to `<any>`, hope this will solve the problem
. Your observable returned `object` and you are trying to assign it to `string`

```
this.httpClientService.post<any>(url, payload, options)
.subscribe(x=>{
     console.log(x)
})
```

Comment: The options parameter in the http post have 'observe' and 'responsetype' settings, maybe something to do with that